# Is there test example for solana wallet-standard?

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter

Is there test example for solana [wallet-standard](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-standard)?
The [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@solana/wallet-adapter-example) I have found seems to be the old one?

This [demo](https://solana-labs.github.io/wallet-adapter/example/) seems to be the latest one, where can I find source code for the same?

I am integrating Solana wallet-standard in my wallet.

Answer (score 1):

The below repository seems to line up with the demo you linked:

https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter

Comment: Hi, it seems to be old example for wallet adapter not wallet selector

Answer (score 0):

In [link](https://github.com/wallet-standard/wallet-standard/tree/master/packages/example) react & dapp are the example, and [this example](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/tree/master/packages/starter/example) from wallet adapter, which can be used for the same